# Cannot connect to streamlit app hosted on EC2 instance

Tags: python, web, amazon-ec2, streamlit, ec2-ami

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to get my streamlit app deployed on an ec2 instance so I can share with others, however I am having trouble connecting to my streamlit app via the browser. I noticed that on my local machine I also have the same issue, when I run the streamlit app locally, I am able to access my streamlit app via local host:

`http://127.0.0.1:8501/`

However the "External URL" and "Network URL" do not work and the page infinitely loads and eventually times out. Here is the external url & network url given by streamlit when you run `streamlit run app.py`

```
Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.


  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Network URL: http://<network_ip>:8501
  External URL: http://<external_ip>:8501
```

I can confirm that I have allowed port 8501 TCP inbound traffic on my local windows machine as well as on the ec2 instance.

Here is my security group config:

[EC2 Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7uvS.png)

How do I make my streamlit application accessible via the given Network URL & External URL by streamlit and not just via localhost:8501?

Would appreciate anyone's advice who has deployed a streamlit web app on an EC2 instance!

I have checked that:

- My ec2 instance is listening on TCP port 8501
- That the streamlit service is running by running "ps aux | grep streamlit"
- Restarting my instance

Answer (score 0):

So this was a bit of a face-palm moment for me, the problem I was encountering was as a result of the internal firewall blocking connections to port 8501 on my corporate network.